# Freezing a header row until another header scrolls on screen

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a way for a row functioning as a header to freeze, but then be replaced by another header row as it scrolls on to screen?

In my example I've got a section called "Benefits", then about 20 rows of information, then when the header "Costs" appears, I'd like for it to replace the frozen header at the top where "Benefits" was.

Is this possible to do in Excel 2010?

Comment: Check out this article here [LINK](http://excel.tips.net/T003446_Switching_Headers_in_a_Frozen_Row.html)

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't an out of the box option that would do what you are expecting!

Comment: Have you tried split windows to view two separate areas of the same sheet?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the more thorough [VBA solution](http://excel.tips.net/T003446_Switching_Headers_in_a_Frozen_Row.html) linked to by [gtwebb](https://superuser.com/users/278012/gtwebb), here's a very quick and straightforward solution if you're simply dealing with two tables of data one above the other.

[image]

Make sure you've used `Insert > Table` for each one, remembering to select `My table has headers`:

[image]

Then when you scroll down notice how the column headers appear where the column letters normally appear.

[image]

When you scroll to the second table, click into the table somewhere (you do need to click) and the column headers will change accordingly.

[image]

This is a very limited approach, but works if you're in a hurry.